# Give me some advice about using DropdownList in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net webpage, I have many DropdownLists. Each DropdownList has many option value that must get from database. This make this page has very large ViewState and very slow when client request this page.

Additional, In this page I must use GridView to show some value and must update this GridView. I use AjaxManager to update control only in GridView and I try to use jQuery Ajax to request data and create option to add into DropdownList using javascript.

However, This approach cannot work to solve this problem because the DropdownList cannot add an option in client side because of Postback and EventValidate.

What are the solutions to make this page faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Lazy Loading for controls, it might help:

http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2009/05/binding-data-to-repeater-using-lazy.html

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3738616/Lazy-Loading-the-ASPNET-AJAX-TabContainer-Control.htm